# FTP stops during image upload and not executing past storeFile()

Tags: android, android-asynctask, ftp

I am uploading image to a web hosting server using apache commons.

Im using AsyncTask and it appears to get stuck at storeFile(), my copyStreamListener seems to finish too early but then do nothing?? the rest of the method is not executed and  The file that gets uploaded is only partially uploaded on to our server (about 30% of the image is visible). FTP reply codes are all okay but it doesnt close the connection or finish the asynctask

BUT

I have tested this on 8 devices and it only effects 3 of them, and not all the time! The devices with the problem are all running on Android 7.0 (Nougat) maybe it has something to do with that?

I dont think there is a problem with the code (because its fine on majority of devices) but here is how im uploading

```
 FTPClient ftp = new FTPClient();
    try {
        ftp.connect(InetAddress.getByName("my.host"));

        if (ftp.login("user", "pass")) {
            Log.i("Server", " --- FTP Logged In --- ");

            ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode(); 
            ftp.setFileType(FTP.BINARY_FILE_TYPE);
            String directory = "/user" + String.valueOf(userID);
            ftp.makeDirectory(directory);
            ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(directory);

            for (int i = 0; i < imageFilePaths.size(); i++) {
                    uploadFile(imageFilePaths.get(i), ftp, directory);                
                }

            ftp.logout();
            ftp.disconnect();

            Log.i("Server", " --- Logged out --- ");

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }




 private void uploadFile(ImageFiles imageFilePaths, FTPClient ftp, String directory) {


    try {

            final File finalFile = new File(imageFilePaths.fullPath);
            final long fileSize = finalFile.length();
            final String filename = String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis());

            BufferedInputStream buffIn = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(finalFile));
            streamListener = new CopyStreamAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void bytesTransferred(long totalBytesTransferred,
                                             int bytesTransferred, long streamSize) {
                    totalFileSizeTrasnfered = totalFileSizeTrasnfered + bytesTransferred;
                    updateProgress();
                    if (totalBytesTransferred == fileSize) {
                        removeCopyStreamListener(streamListener);
                    }
                }
            };
            ftp.setCopyStreamListener(streamListener);

            // excecution seems to stop here
            boolean result = ftp.storeFile(filename + imageFilePaths.fileExt, buffIn);
            Log.i("Server", " --- File uploaded --- " + result);

           buffIn.close();



        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

All that shows up in the logcat after logging in is...

```
 I/Server:  --- FTP Logged In --- 
 I/art: Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 2256(150KB) AllocSpace objects, 3(35MB) LOS objects, 13% free, 104MB/120MB, paused 2.157ms total 118.293ms
 D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfofornetcontext+,hn 29(0x70616765616432),sn(),hints(known),family 0,flags 1024, proc=com.proj.myproj
 D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy get netid:0
 D/libc: [NET] android_getaddrinfo_proxy-, success
 V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

No "logged out" or "file uploaded" and the app continues to run.

Can anyone give me any insight on how to solve or point me in the right direction? Thank you

Comment: Is this really the minimal code that reproduces the problem? Cannot you simplify it further (single file, no stream listener, etc.) to narrow down the problem?

Comment: `All that shows up in the logcat after logging in is...`. Then add much more log statements to your code. Also in the catch blocks. Find out which is the last one logged.

Comment: `V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service`.

Comment: Is it necessary to install a new stream listener for every file? Why is the variable not local to the function?

Comment: Put a log statement in bytesTransferred() printing all parameters.

Comment: `updateProgress();`. Please elaborate.

Comment: `ftp.makeDirectory(directory);`. I think you should only call that if the directory does not exist.

Comment: `removeCopyStreamListener()`. Cant you better do that after storeFile()? Then it will always be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the reply does everyone.    I have tried logging in bytes transformed... If run as you would expect but only for a small percentage of the file.   It says totalBytesTransferred == fileSize and the listener is removed but then nothing further.

Comment: The problem also occurs if I remove the stramlisterener.   And if I only is file input stream instead of buffered input stream.

Comment: I will try moving the move stream listetener to after store file.    But the code is fine on several devices.  so I doubt it will solve my issue. Updateprogress() simply tell as listener to update a progress bar on my ui